# Set environment variables using SSH

Tags: unix, shell, ssh

I am trying to execute unix command using SSH from cygwin. My set of command would navigate to a certain directory, source a particular file. Based on the variables sourced from that file, I would try to launch application. But somehow the variables are not getting sourced as echo does not return any values. Could someone let me know what am I missing here

Contents of the environment variables file (myenv) are

```
export TEST_DATA="DATA1:DATA2"
```

and I am executing the following command

```
$ ssh kunal@kspace "ls; cd /disk1/kunal/env; . ./myenv; echo $TEST_DATA; "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes do not inhibit expansion. Use single quotes instead.

That is, the variable is being expanded on your side, not on the server you're SSHing to.

Comment: is there anyway where I can use both?
What I mean is, I have some variables in local machine which I would like to pass to ssh for local expansion. Also depending on the variables file, I would like to echo the variables for which I do not want the local expansion!

Comment: Sure. Just switch them up. `ssh ... 'echo $remote'"$local"`

Answer (score 1):

Because `$TEST_DATA` is in double quotes, its value is being interpolated by your local shell (the one you called `ssh` in). If you use single quotes it will pass the literal `$TEST_DATA` across as part of the ssh command to be executed on the far side.

Comment: +1! It works with single quotes. However I am looking a way where I can use both kind of variables. One which should be expanded locally and another should be expanded remotely.